# How can I access the vim installed with the anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, windows, vim

I've started the Anaconda python distribution. This comes with something called
'Anaconda prompt' that has conda and git available at the Windows command line.
When I make a commit from this command line, Vim comes up as the editor.
When I type 'vim' or 'vi' at this prompt I get the message:

> 'vim' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

**How can I access vim from the Anaconda prompt?**

Comment: Are you talking about the CLI anaconda 'something' or conda 'something'?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using vim or vi commands because the package was not installed on my machine. To use the vim command of anaconda prompt with windows os, then use this given command ' conda install -c conda-forge vim '. This command will install the required dependencies and then just simply use the vim command example - vim file_name.

[Reference](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/vim)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am on a mac, but have been using the anaconda prompt on my Windows work machine. You need to add the path of the vim tool to the Windows path environmental variable. I set mine up to use notepad++ when I did a recent install. You can probably find vim in the %APPDATA% directory where anaconda is located if you installed it under the user and not the system. If you search for vim there, you might fine it. If it isn't there it might have gotten installed with another tool.

Answer (score 0):

Install PyVim instead as below and open your textual files in your Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install pyvim
```